# Get value ID on sheet to edit or update the data from list in another sheet using VBA-Excel

Tags: excel, vba

About the problem, how to update if the cell ID is true with button via vba-excel, so I need to update some values from sheet 1 a table column to another sheet a List of data.

For sample :

**In Sheet1** (Edit or update any values of cells)

[image]

**In Sheet2** (Get the data updated if the ID is true)

[image]

```
Sub update()
Dim LR1 As Long
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A" & LR1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    .Range("B" & LR1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
    .Range("C" & LR1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
    .Range("D" & LR1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
End With
End Sub
```

I hope anyone help me to resolve the issue

Comment: VLOOKUP function, or INDEX/MATCH functions.

Comment: Use Find() to locate the matching row (if present) then update that row

Comment: Can you not use `PasteSpecial` with `Transpose = True`, as the headers are in same order. Also what is the error you are getting in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Find()` to locate the matching row (if present) then update that row: if not found then add a new row

```
Sub update()
Dim f As Range, sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set f = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=sht1.Range("B1").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If f Is Nothing Then Set f = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    f.Resize(1, 5).Value = Application.Transpose(sht1.Range("B1:B5").Value)
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: cell-by-cell if you need more control over what goes where

```
Sub update()

    Dim f As Range, sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set f = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=sht1.Range("B1").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then Set f = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        With f.EntireRow
            .Cells(1).Value = sht1.Range("B1").value
            'skip one cell then copy the rest...
            .Cells(3).Resize(1, 4).Value = Application.Transpose(sht1.Range("B4:B5").Value)
            'etc etc
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code and screenshots for sheet1 do not match up - in your code you put B2 into columnA, but in your screenshot the ID is in B1.  Figure out your actual layout and make the necessary adjustments.  I did make one edit above to change 4 --> 5

Comment: I did, i say it's ok, thank you much. But, i have doubt how can I skip a column? For example in sheet 2 skip the column B when the data update. Any way to reeplace the code f.resize ... ?

Comment: You'd go back to your cell-by cell method - see edit above

Comment: Thank you again!. I tested, it's a simple ok, so i have to make similar but with 65 lines with skipe one column (B). lol. maybe, i must to include with for ?.

Comment: It's not just a choice of one line or 65...  You can use both the cell-by-cell approach for individual cells *and* the resize() approach for any block of contiguous cells  See my update above.

Comment: Thank you much Tim Williams!. Solved issue.